# Calling JNI_CreateJavaVM function twice

Tags: java, c++, c, java-native-interface

I'm using a library that calls the `JNI_CreateJavaVM` function inside the library code. However, I also need some JNI Wrappings and I need to call the same function `JNI_CreateJavaVM` to get the `JNIEnv*` to my application.

But the second call is failing.

is there any way to do this?

The library does not support getting or setting the `JNIEnv*` created inside the library.

Comment: if you put some code to explain what you are doing i can look at it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot create more than one JVM from the same process:

> As of JDK/JRE 1.2 , creation of multiple VMs in a single process is not supported.

You may be able to attach your current thread to the existing JVM though using `AttachCurrentThread` function. See [the docs for the Invocation API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html). The [equivalent document in Java 15](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/specs/jni/invocation.html#jni_getcreatedjavavms) simply states:

> Creation of multiple VMs in a single process is not supported.

You will need a pointer to the `JavaVM` object. See if `JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs()` can help you, I'm not sure if this is per-process (in which case it will only ever be a single element list) or per machine. In either case the `JavaVM` will have to be the one that the library is using or you probably will not be doing what you want. If you can access that then you should be able to make invocations on other objects in your Java application, but make sure that it is thread-safe.